# Two polls not working in a same JSF page when used with render

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to switch between polls on change of a checkbox. But only one poll is successfully called in the bean.

```
 <h:form id="route_form">
   <p:poll interval="10" listener="#{userAction.getVehicleLocFromMap}" onstart="startloading();single();" oncomplete="closeloading();" update="@form" rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq false}"></p:poll>
   <p:poll interval="10" listener="#{userAction.getAllVehiclesForTracking}" onstart="startloading();all();" oncomplete="closeloading();complete();" update="@form" rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq true}"></p:poll>
   <h:inputHidden id="passengers" value ="#{userAction.passengerlistJSON}" rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq false}"/>
   <h:inputHidden id="current_loc_lat" value="#{userAction.triptoTrack.veh_latitude}" rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq false}"/>
   <h:inputHidden id="current_loc_lon" value="#{userAction.triptoTrack.veh_longitude}" rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq false}"/>
   <h:inputHidden id="vehicle_number" value="#{userAction.triptoTrack.vehicle_RegNo}" rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq false}"/>
   <h:inputHidden id="cabsJSON" value="#{userAction.allVehicles}" rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq true}"/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4" align="left" style="vertical-align: middle">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="showAllCabs" value="#{userAction.showAllCabs}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{userAction.backButtonTest}" onstart="startloading();" oncomplete="closeloading();" update="@form" onsuccess="location.reload(true);"></p:ajax>
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputText value="Show all cabs" styleClass="dropdown_label" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

I tried placing poll in separate forms. But didn't work.

Comment: Instead of `rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq true}"` do `rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs}"`. Instead of `rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq false}"` do `rendered="#{!userAction.showAllCabs}"`.

Comment: No it didn't work. What good does using rendered="#{!userAction.showAllCabs}" over rendered="#{userAction.showAllCabs eq false}" do?

Comment: It doesn't change anything functionally, just a sane way to do boolean expressions. No point in comparing `true eq true`.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Only one of your polls will be rendered, because they have opposite `rendered` conditions. And why is there `location.reload`? Is it relevant to the question? What's the point of having `update` and `oncomplete`, when your `location.reload` says to leave the page?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to render only one poll at a given instance. When the checkbox is unselected the other poll should be rendered which is not happening. And regarding the location.reload, I have a mapbox which needs to be reloaded with the data got from the poll. And the oncomplete method stops the loading effect in the UI which is started when the button is clicked. So I have called functions in onstart and oncomplete.

Comment: What is the scope of the userAction bean? `location.reload` probably results in a new userAction bean with resetted showAllCabs field.

Comment: The scope of UserAction is session. And I'm not setting any value to showAllCabs in bean. I tried checking whether the poll is calling or not by printing in console in Javascript, its printing. But the bean listener is not gettting called.